# Check if all inputs with a certain class are empty using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if all input fields with a certain class are empty. 
Right now I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<button class="check-fields">Check Fields</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.check-fields').on('click', function () {

  var value = $('.required-entry').filter(function () {
    return this.value != '';
  });

  if (value.length == 0) {
    alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
  } else if (value.length > 0) {
    alert('Everything has a value.');
  }
});
```

But this throws the message "Everything has a value." if ANY one of the inputs has a value. I'm trying to only throw that message when every input with this class has something in it.

```js
$('.check-fields').on('click', function () {

    var value = $('.required-entry').filter(function () {
        return this.value != '';
    });

    if (value.length == 0) {
        console.log('Please fill out all required fields.');
    } else if (value.length > 0) {
        console.log('Everything has a value.');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<button class="check-fields">Check Fields</button>
```

I also have this fiddle with slightly different code.. also throws the Everything has a value message when the first input is the only one filled.

```js
$('.check-fields').on('click', function () {
    
    if($.trim($('.required-entry').val()) === '') {
        console.log('Please fill out all required fields.');
    } else {
        console.log('Everything has a value.');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<button class="check-fields">Check Fields</button>
```

Comment: Compare for `this.value === '';` This way you know that at least 1 has nothing in it.

Comment: What? instead of `return this.value != '';`? This makes it always say please fill out all required fields

Comment: Dhaval's answer elaborates..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

check the following code:

```
$('.check-fields').on('click', function () {

    var reqlength = $('.required-entry').length;
    console.log(reqlength);
    var value = $('.required-entry').filter(function () {
        return this.value != '';
    });

    if (value.length>=0 && (value.length !== reqlength)) {
        alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
    } else {
        alert('Everything has a value.');
    }
});
```

Comment: That did it! Makes sure they're all filled!

Answer (score 5):

You might have to change condition for the same like following, Do empty checking.

```
var value = $('.required-entry').filter(function () {
    return this.value === '';
});
```

Depends on above condition you can change `if` condition, you will get `0` count if all inputs have value, other wise `>0` count.

```
if (value.length == 0) {
   alert('Everything has a value.');
} 
else if (value.length > 0) {
    alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
}
```

Example

```js
$('.check-fields').on('click', function () {
 var value = $('.required-entry').filter(function () {
    return this.value === '';
  });
  if (value.length == 0) {alert('Everything has a value.');
  } else if (value.length > 0) {
    alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<input type="text" class="required-entry">
<button class="check-fields">Check Fields</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
           alert('Please fill out all required fields.');

        }
        else {
            alert('Everything has a value.');

        }
    });
```

or

```
 $('input[class="required-entry"]').each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
           alert('Please fill out all required fields.');

        }
        else {
            alert('Everything has a value.');

        }
    });
```

Comment: This makes the alert pop up for each and every input field that is empty. I want to check all input fields, and popup the message once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could settle for

```
<input type="text" class="semantic-classname" required />
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Comment: It's to stop a button from doing something, not at the form submit button yet.