# Display error message in the same dialog popup in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, popup, asp.net-mvc-partialview, error-messaging

I have a MVC application where I implemented an advance search dialog popup. If the user do not type anything in any of the textbox and they click the search button, I want to keep the popup open and display the error message on the same popup. My problem is that it will close that dialog popup and display the textbox for advance search and error message on the main page instead. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Index View

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AdvSearch">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <p style="font-weight: bold" class="modal-title">Advance Search</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="AdvanceSearchForm">
                    @Html.Partial("AdvSrchForm")
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p align="left">% accepts wildcard</p></td>
                        <td width="320px"></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" id="ASearchbtn" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ASearchbtn").click(function () {

        var form = $('#AdvanceSearchForm');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        form.validate();
        var ASData = $("#AdvanceSearchForm").serialize();

        if (form.valid())
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/SearchPayment/SubLookup",
                data: ASData,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#AdvSearch").modal("hide");
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                    $('#ASGrid').html('');
                    $('#ASGrid').html(response);
                    $('#ASGrid').show();
                    $("#DataList").hide();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
})
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AdvanceSearch(Payments filter)
    {

        Session.Clear();
        //get data from db base on filter
        if (!((filter.fName ?? filter.LName ?? filter.grp ?? filter.sec ?? filter.zip ?? filter.hPhone ?? filter.SSN) == null && filter.bday == null))
        {
            model = GetUserSession(filter);

            model = (PremiumPayments)Session["PaymentData"];
            return PartialView("SubscriberGrid", model);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ErrMsg = "Invalid Search - At least one field is required.";
            return PartialView("AdvSrchForm");
        }
    }
```

Advance Search Form (Partial View)

```
@model PaymentFinder.Models.PremiumPayments

<table class="advsrchfrm">
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("First Name %")</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.fName, new { @class = "form-control"}
</td>
        <td>@Html.Label("Last Name %")</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Birthdate")</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.bday, "", new { placeholder = 
DateTime.Now.ToString("d") })</td>
        <td>@Html.Label("Phone #")</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.hPhone, new { @class = "form-control" })
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Zip Code")</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.zip, new { @class = "form-control" })
</td> 
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

@if (//condition to display this)
{
    <span class="text-danger" style="font-weight: 
bold">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrMsg)</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you a doing a post and the page refresh completely. Why not do the validation using jQuery and if everything is valid then do the post.

Comment: How can I go about doing it? Sorry, this is my first MVC project.

Comment: Hi, you can use something like `var test = $(":input").val()` to very if at least one of the inputs have a value. You can do a if statement in the `$("#ASearchbtn").click(function (){})` you have and if it pass then run the ajax

Comment: Where should I put my error message? Also, if it doesn't pass, how can I refresh the popup modal to display the error message?

Comment: I don't see where you are using the `ViewBag.ErrMsg` in your view, but you can use a simple <span> or a <div> and with jquery do something like `$("#divOrSpanID`).text("your message here");` if it doesn't pass

Comment: I have this code that grabs user input `var ASData = $("#ASForm").serialize()` following what you said, I did `if(ASData != null) {//ajax call}` but it still does the ajax call even if there is no user input

Comment: Oh I'm using the ViewBag.ErrMsg on my partial view that contains the advance search form. Since I want to display the error message on the same popup modal I figured I should put the error message there and put an if statement on whether to display it or not

Comment: Hi, please if you can post the code with the changes so I can see better what you do and better help you. Also do you verify that `ASData` is null when you do not enter anything?

Comment: I edited my post above with my updated code, I also included the advance search form partial view. It's not doing a post anymore if the fields are empty, so I just need to get it to display the error message on the same popup modal when there is no user input when search button is clicked.

Comment: what you can do is this `<span id= "errormsg" class="text-danger" style="font-weight: bold"></span>` note that i give the `<span>` an id and with it you can just use jquery when the condition are not met like this `$("#errormsg).text("your message here");`. you don't need to use the viewbag anymore and remember to clear the span message `$("#errormsg).text("");` when the conditions met

Comment: I just did exactly what you said, but for some reason it's not changing the text on my span when form is not valid. So I have `if(form.valid()){ $("ErrMsg).text("") //ajax call }` //this part works, `else{ $("ErrMsg).text("At least one field is required")}` //this doesn't work. It doesn't close my popup modal but it's also not displaying the error message. I added the span in my advance search form. Could it be that it's not hitting my else statement?

Comment: So I manage fix this issue, but I have a feeling that I'm doing it wrong, cause when the fields are empty it actually goes to the `error:` part of my ajax call. It really wasn't hitting the else part of my statement. What I did is I added the error message inside the error section of my ajax call `error: function(error) { $("ErrMsg).text("At least one field is required"); }` Is this ok or should I fix this?

Comment: Hi, what i see from the advanced search view is that you have a form.valid but you did not specify which field is required so the form is always valid. I suggest you use instead the value of the variable `ASData` for the if statement because if you use the required attribute all of the field must contain a value

Comment: It's not working, validator.unobtrusive.parse(ASData), does not like that ASData is serialized().

Comment: can you do a console.log and show me what the ASData show when all the fields are empty

Comment: It says `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognize expression: fName=&LName=&...` it's pretty much a list of my fileds.

Comment: in that case i suggest using this approach mentioned by Srinu in [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923968/check-if-all-inputs-with-a-certain-class-are-empty-using-jquery) he use a class to verify if the field have a value